# Why the output of the following code is 2 and 0

Tags: c++, increment

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x = 0;
  cout << ++x << "   " << x++ << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the output is `2`  and `0`

why is that !?

Comment: why not? why do you care? Seriously, if you want to write code that outputs eg `1 0` you would write `std::cout << "1 0";` and not something that obfuscated

Comment: Notice that you would have expected behavior since C++17.

Comment: This is asked every week. Strange, considering it's code that nobody should ever write! Where did you see this code? Why did you write this code? Were you taught it?